# Kafka-Python consume last unread message

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have two microservices.

1. MProducer - sending messages to kafka queue
2. MConsumer - reading messages from kafka queue

When consumer crashes and restart, I want to continue consuming from last message.

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
                         auto_offset_reset='latest',
                         enable_auto_commit=False)
```

Comment: What do you get instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using [kafka-python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python), so you'll need to pass the `group_id` argument to your Consumer. See the description for this argument in the [KafkaConsumer documentation](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html).

By setting a group id, the Consumer will periodically commit its position to Kafka and will automatically retrieve it upon restarting.

Answer (score 0):

You do that by having a consumer group. Assuming you're using confluent library then just add `'group.id': 'your-group'`
When the service is down then coming up, it will start from last committed point.

The information about each consumer group is saved in a special topic in Kafka (starting from v0.9) called `__consumer_offsets`. More info in kafka docs [https://kafka.apache.org/intro#intro_consumers]

Comment: thanks for support, I added group-id and it works now.